# JPA remove from @ManyToMany and merge Non-Owning side

Tags: jpa, merge, many-to-many, eclipselink

## TL;DR

I want my persistence provider (EclipseLink 2.6.0) to issue `DELETE` statements on join tables **invoking merge on the non-owning side** of a bidirectional `@ManyToMany`.

Invoking merge on the owning side is not permitted (by requirement).

---

Suppose you have two entities

```
@Entity
public class Account extends AbstractEntity
{
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    @JoinTable(name = "ACCOUNT_PERSON", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ACCOUNT_ID"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID"))
    private List<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Person extends Subject
{
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "personList", cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
    private List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

So, `Account` owns the relationship.

Suppose you have loaded `Person1` which has this structure:

```
Person1
    Account1
        Person1
        Person2

    Account2
        Person1
        Person3
```

and this structure maps to this join table:

```
+------------+-----------+
| ACCOUNT_ID | PERSON_ID |
+------------+-----------+
|         A1 |        P1 |
|         A1 |        P2 |
|         A2 |        P1 |
|         A2 |        P3 |
+------------+-----------+
```

now, detach `Account1` and `Person1` on both sides using `p1.getAccountList().remove(a1); a1.getPersonList().remove(p1);`

so, we end up with this structure:

```
Person1
    Account2
        Person1
        Person3

Account1
    Person2
```

At last, invoke `em.merge(p1)` and **obviously** no SQL is issued on the join table, since merge does not cascade to `Account1` (which is the owning side) because it is not in the list anymore.

The question: is it possible to achieve the removal invoking merge on the non-owning side?

I know that i can simply `em.merge(p1); em.merge(a1);` **but i don't want to**: I'm asking this question to find a generic way to "virtually" make each `@ManyToMany` an owning side.

This will extremely simplify the application code, allowing a **REAL** relational-independent approach.

At a first think, these comes in my mind:

1. use a `@Transient` list to store removed objects and cascade merge to them during `@PreUpdate`
2. use a EclipseLink `DescriptorCustomizer` to intercept `preUpdateWithChanges()` and cascade merge on removed objects
3. map two unidirectional `@ManyToMany` to have both sides as owner
4. maybe something similar to `orphanRemoval` (but on join tables only) exists in the deep of EclipseLink

Suggestions?